# url encoding issue. instead %50 its passing space..how to pass %50 through urlencoded url

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have tried to pass a variable trough url... its %50.
I am doing urlencoding to pass other languages through the url.
At that time %50 also been converted to a space or something else.

Can anyone help me to find out a way to send %50 as a variable through urlencoded link(url).

Comment: `url encode` and `url decode`

Comment: please read the question properly... while decoding url the above is happing and I am unable to see %50 after decoding... I need encoding and decoding.. but still i need to pass %50.,.. how can i pass.. with url encoding property....

Comment: Why is your question tagged `mysql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = '%50';

echo $encoded = urlencode($string);
// returns %2550

echo urldecode($encoded);
// returns %50

?>
```

So if you want to pass `$string` to a url you write something like:

```
http://yoursite.com/script.php?string=$encoded
```

To get your original string value you can just use `$_GET` in your `script.php`:

```
echo $_GET["string"];
// returns %50
```

Comment: Hi... when I passing it through a url to another one server... its not returning as %50 but a empty space.... the solution whatever you mention is working out in the same page. But not server to server... create a string starts with %50 and pass it through a url to another server and try.. its not really working out.

Comment: What do you mean with 'server to server' ? Show us what you really want to do!

Comment: I mean a domain to another.... both is in different server... By that time its returning space instead %50... advice please...

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and post the necessary code that you have written so far? I have no clue what you are really trying to do.